# Login Form doesn't work

Tags: c#, authentication

I have this login code that it works if there is only one user in database but if i add another user and then login with that account the message "Wrong username or password" pops up but then when i click OK it redirect me to Form1.

```
 private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = zivali.sqlite");
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login;";

        SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string username = reader["username"].ToString();
            string password = reader["password"].ToString();


                if (username == textBoxUserName.Text && password == textBoxPassword.Text)
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                    f1.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
                }

        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your login success/fail code runs for every login in the db. That's why you get N-1 wrong username messageboxes and 1 successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one user the while loop will loop once. So the while checks if the user exists if not it will show a message box.

If you have more than one user. Than the while loop will run X times. But when it loops for the firs time and the credentials does not match with the given than it will show the message box.

You said that you've added a second user. So when you login with that second user the first user while looping will be false. That is why it is showing the message box.

To solve this you can try something like this:

```
       SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = zivali.sqlite");
        conn.Open();
        SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(conn);

        com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login;";

        SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        // place your username/password decleration here, no need to read them X times in a loop
        string username = reader["username"].ToString();
        string password = reader["password"].ToString();

        // bool for if there is any user whith the given cridentials
        bool loginValid = false;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // if cridentials mathch set loginValid to true and break out of the loop 
            if (username == textBoxUserName.Text && password == textBoxPassword.Text)
            {
                loginValid = true;
                break;

            }
        }

        // check if the login is true
        if (loginValid)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            f1.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but now i get this error message InvalidOperationException: no current row error here is a link to a picture of error: http://imgur.com/vUMLoS2

Comment: I think I made a mistake try move these rows: `string username = reader["username"].ToString();
        string password = reader["password"].ToString();` into the while loop like you had before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to not make your decision inside your `while`statement, you may should do something like the following:

```
 bool doesMatch = false;
 string username = reader["username"].ToString();
 string password = reader["password"].ToString();


 while (reader.Read())
 {
       if (username == textBoxUserName.Text && password == textBoxPassword.Text)
      {
            doesMatch = true;
      }
 } 
 if (doesMatch)
 {
    this.Hide();
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.ShowDialog();
 }
 else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong username or password");
 }
```

Or you could just add `WHERE` statement to your query to check if there is a row in your table has a user with the same data as the entered username and password.